# How to make sure which version of Python I need?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have hard to find the distinction of which Python is needed when I download some Python project. I know that there is difference between **python2** `print "Hello world"` and **python3** `print("Hello world")`, but not so much more.

For example, there is some interesting [demo](https://github.com/mbrochh/react-apollo-graphql-demo) to try, but after following instructions given there, I still got it not working. So I wonder, does it need version 3 or 2? Needless to say, this project does not use `print` anywhere ;)

So, what are the key differences in syntax level which may help a beginner to deduct, is there needed Python2 or Python3?

This question is not about getting to run the demo mentioned above, it is about making the distinction of Python versions because this is not the first time to me to wonder about the same problem, because pythonists seem not to point it in their projects very often.

Comment: Generally the documentation should tell you. Python 2 is EOL, if you're using any halfway recent code it *should* all be Python 3 now. Only very *very* old projects may require Python 2 these days.

Comment: Python2 is not longer supported. You should always target Python3 and unless the code uses some weird Python2-specific things, it's easy to port (or even will work as is).

Comment: @h4z3 Thank you, if I ever target something, it is certainly v3, but I am not sure about others seldom ;)

Comment: @deceze in particular case the author uses `mkvirtualenv`, which AFAIK is from v2 tooling. So what could I conclude?

Comment: @w.k virtualenvwrapper / mkvirtualenv works just fine in Python 3, and people who used it with Python 2 generally still use it with 3 as they like the workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly state the most obvious check is **print** but I would like to provide a few of extra suggestions to quickly and precisely understand if the code you are using was written for Python 2 or Python 3.

**Check for Python 3 linting**
Use [PyLint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) specifying the --py3k parameter

**Check script compilation**

You can use this commands to check if your code compiles for Python 2 and / or Python 3:

```
$ python2 -m py_compile foo.py
$ python3 -m py_compile foo.py
```

This can give you a quick solution in case you get a compiling error for one of the two.

**Check 2to3 output**

In case that you have code that runs in both Python versions but doesn't work properly in one of the two you can also try running the "2 to 3" converter available here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

This converter was used to convert a script from Python 2 to Python 3.
In case conversion is suggested it is quite probable that you are looking at a Python 2 script.

**Run code in two different Virtual Environments**

The very final test would be creating two distinct virtualenvs, one with Python 3 and one with Python 2 and check the code functionality in both.

All those methods seem to me easier, faster and less error prone than manually checking the code.

Comment: Seems, that on syntactic level is hard to tell which version is needed. I accept your answer as it contains additional efforts to distinguish the difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your example demo project has various hints that it is for Python2.

1. In `backend/manage.py` the first line is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Unless the code was written to be run on Arch Linux, this executable will be Python2.

2. In `backend/simple_app/*`, many of the files have this line:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

This would not be needed in Python3 because all strings are unicode strings.

3. The project was last updated 3 years ago.

Comment: It could also perfectly well be cross-compatible…

Comment: It could be, but even something that is cross compatible is still (partially) for Python2.

Comment: Are you sure about the first point? I always thought, this shebang would invoke the virtual env's python interpreter, regardless of whether that's python2 or python3?

Comment: I've modded my system quite a bit, so maybe this is just me, but regardless of what venv I'm in `/usr/bin/env python` accesses the system python. Also I was always told to use `/usr/bin/env python3` if that was the desired version.

Comment: After reading a bit on this, it seems to depend on the OS.
For Windows systems `python` defaults to `python2` (see [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/#python-version-qualifiers)), whereas on UNIX like systems it might call either `python2` or `python3` (see [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/#for-python-runtime-distributors)).
So, specifying exactly which version of the python interpreter needs to be used, seems to be the way to go.

Comment: First, you try to solve my question as specific to the example, but I look for general approach on syntactic level to make distinction which Python it might be. Second, I got this example to work with v3.